# Connecting to a Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i'm totally new to Rails and Postgres + Heroku. I've developed a web and just like PHP you can see what are the records user has entered and key in with phpMyAdmin however what about Rails? How can I see the records?

I've uploaded the app to Heroku so now I wanna see my Production's data. What is more is that my test and development data can't be seen in PGAdmin as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Heroku Postgres just as you can a local database.

Go to https://postgres.heroku.com/databases, select the database, and it will display the connection settings. On the far right of the page there is an icon with two arrows on it, and selecting it will give you the connection string for various technologies, including a psql command line you can just copy and paste to a terminal.

It will look something like:

```
psql "dbname=ddgadagin host=ec2-107-12-168-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com user=dgddgargarg password=huu55ihfwqreergr port=5432 sslmode=require"
```