# Connecting locally to a HerokuConnect Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm building a simple web app that will deploy on Heroku, and using a Postgres database that is filled with an object from Salesforce. I did that with HerokuConnect and that works.

Now I want to see the contents of the database so that I know the table names, and I already know you can't do that on Heroku itself. So, I tried to connect to the database locally via `heroku pg:psql` but everytime I do that I get the error:

```
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "***.***.***.**" (**.***.***.***) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port ****?
```

So that doesn't work. I tried the following but to no avail:

- explicitly specifiying the name of the database
- specifying host, user, database name, password, port and setting `sslmode=require` per the [user guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress) and [this question about connecting to a heroku postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621963/connecting-to-a-heroku-postgresql-database).
- using the method above, but instead of using `heroku psql` I just used `psql`. That asked for a password but for a user I never created (a user with my corporate system name, because this is a corporate laptop)
- reinstalling Postgres

Running `heroku pg:info` correctly lists my database information.

I am missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Can you try using the config var for DATABASE_URL and do from the command line `psql <configvarvalue>` - if not - please open a support ticket and we'll dig into it.

Comment: That worked once, but couldn't get it to work this morning. I'll fool around a bit more and then open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

"DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" is not an error but it's only a warning.
This is due to an issue with Ruby 2 on Windows.

Comment: Could that be the reason why the connection was refused?

Comment: Apparently not @Lodybo